# Add warning for wrong date while user manually fill date in odoo

Tags: date, datetime, odoo, odoo-14

I want to show warning on date field when user fills date manually instead of filling through date picker and the date is incorrect. Suppose user manually enters the date like **35/13/2022** which is a incorrect date. So instead of removing this incorrect date and saving previously updated date, I want to set a warning message while saving the record "please enter correct date".

**Current Behaviour:- when user enter "32/13/2022" and click on save, it saves previously stored/saved date in database.**

**Expected Behaviour :- when user enter "32/13/2022" and click on save, It should show a warning that date is incorrect.**

**Note:- I want this warning in all date fields even in default modules.**

Do anyone have any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below Js code to add notification warning when user will enter wrong date into datepicker.

```
odoo.define('your_module_name.date_picker', function (require) {
"use strict";

    var core = require('web.core');
    var DatePicker = require('web.datepicker')

    var dateWidget = DatePicker.DateWidget
    var _t = core._t;

    var DateWidget = dateWidget.include({

        changeDatetime: function () {
            if (!this.isValid()) {
                this.displayNotification({title:_t("Validate Error. "),
                                message: _t('Please Enter Valid Date.'),
                                type: 'warning',
                                sticky: false

                });
                this.$input.val('');
            } else {
                this._super.apply(this, arguments);
            }
        },
    });

    return {
        DateWidget: DateWidget,
    };
});
```

Comment: hello Sidharth, Thanks for the response but it is still saving previous stored date if the date is invalid although it shows the warning but saving previous stored date if it is incorrect.